# Debian Jessie (8) using the Parallels desktop

Tags: debian, osx, kernel-modules, parallels

I have installed the Debian Jessie (8) using the Parallels desktop in the MacBook Pro host. It goes fine for some time and now I keep getting message,

```
some of the required kernel modules are missing. To solve this problem, please try to reinstall Parallels Tools using the virtual machine menu
```

How do I install the required kernel modules?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried reinstalling Parallels Tools like the message says? That would seem to fix the problem you're having.

Comment: Yes, this is what I have done and the problem is solved. This was the first time I was using the Linux and asked some bad questions in the forum. Now, I certainly know this was not appropriate but, I already get banned from asking new questions.

Comment: Now, this is been 2.5 months with Linux and I'm good with the OS. Would you mind to upvote the question if you like? With some of this effort, I can ask \ questions here again and put efforts to improve the community